# org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table - add item

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to add an item to the email column and to the remove column. How do you accomplish this?
I keep looking for a add method or something but I have no been able to find anything.
I have tried setData and redraw after setting some string but this did not work.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    Table emailTable = new Table(composite_2, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    FormData fd_table = new FormData();
    fd_table.bottom = new FormAttachment(emailText, -3);
    fd_table.top = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
    fd_table.right = new FormAttachment(emailLabel, 481);
    fd_table.left = new FormAttachment(emailLabel, 0, SWT.LEFT);
    Table emailTable.setLayoutData(fd_table);
    Table emailTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
    Table emailTable.setLinesVisible(true);

    TableColumn emailColumn = new TableColumn(emailTable, SWT.NONE);
    TableColumn emailColumn.setWidth(377);
    TableColumn emailColumn.setText("Email");

    TableColumn removeColumn = new TableColumn(emailTable, SWT.NONE);
    TableColumn removeColumn.setWidth(100);
    TableColumn removeColumn.setText("Remove");
```

Comment: Does this help? http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWT/article.html#swt_table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create `TableItem`s with first argument in the constructor `emailTable` and set their text as described in http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWT/article.html#swt_table:

```
        TableItem item = new TableItem(emailTable, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText (0, "test@example.org");
```